# Dos formularios conflictivos en `PHP`

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo un formulario en la pagina principal para actualizar saldos y otro en una ventana modal para registrar compras, así:

```
<!-- Con este botón llamo al modal Registrar Compras-->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegistrarCompras">
  Registrar Turno
</button>

<!-- Formulario para Actualizar Saldos -->
<form role="form" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="actualizarSaldos" class="btn btn-danger">
    Actualizar Saldos
  </button>
  <!-- Todos los campos del formulario para actualizar saldos-->
  <?php
     $ActualizarSaldos = new ControladorSaldos();
     $ActualizarSaldos -> ctrActualizarSaldos();
  ?>
</form>

<!-- Modal Registrar Compras -->
<div id="modalRegistrarCompras" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <form role="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <!-- Todos los campos del formulario para registrar compras-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      Registrar Compras
    </button>
    <?php
      $registrarCompra = new ControladorCompras();
      $registrarCompra -> ctrRegistrarCompras();
    ?>
  </form>
</div>
```

La idea es registrar varias compras desde el modal y luego actualizar saldos una sola vez desde la pagina principal.

***Notese que los dos controladores son diferentes.***

El problema que tengo es que al registrar una compra, se ejecuta el controlador de saldos y no el de compras. Llegué a esta conclusión tras comentar estas dos líneas de código:

```
<?php
  //$ActualizarSaldos = new ControladorSaldos();
  //$ActualizarSaldos -> ctrActualizarSaldos();
?>
```

**Las dos acciones por separado funcionan**, es decir, con estas dos líneas de código comentadas, las compras *a través del modal* se registran correctamente. Luego, si quiero actualizar saldos, habilito estas dos líneas de código y se actualizan los saldos correctamente.

Mi duda es:

¿Qué debo cambiar en el código para que ambos formularios inserten la información de manera independiente en la tabla que les corresponde, sin que entren en conflicto los dos controladores?

Comment: Es más que nada un problema de **organización del código**. De entrada hace daño a la vista que dentro de cada etiqueta `form` tengas código PHP que crea instancias de los controladores ¿ ? El hecho de que en cada `form` se cree una instancia para compras o para saldo no significa que la otra no se va a crear cada vez que se carga o se refresca la página. La mejor manera de resolver esto sería con Ajax, incluso podrías prescindir del modal e integrar todo en la misma página, mostrando u ocultando el formulario según convenga. Hoy día puedes olvidarte de los modales, es algo del pasado siglo.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Tendré muy en cuenta tus comentarios. Veré que puedo lograr a través de `Ajax` ya que la información que intento enviar, en cada caso, no es un formulario simple sino una tabla con múltiples datos. No sabía que los modales están en desuso, pues veo que `Bootstrap 4` aún los incluye. _Eso indica que aún me falta muchísimo por aprender!_

Comment: Bootstrap los incluye porque mucha gente todavía los usa, pero si lo piensas bien un modal es un punto negativo desde el punto de vista de experiencia del usuario. Hoy día, gracias a Ajax, puedes concebir una página como un escritorio donde tienes todo integrado, pudiendo mostrar/ocultar o bien activar/desactivar  parte de ese escritorio en vez de sacar un modal, que al fin y al cabo es otra ventana. O sea puedes tener un área de la misma ventana para recoger datos y actualizar de forma automática otra área en base a esos datos sin necesidad de un modal. Y esos datos pueden estar en servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que tienes ambas acciones en el mismo archivo. y ambas apuntan a la misma ruta. no importa por cual formulario llegue siempre se ejecutan las 2 acciones que tienes declarada en tu archivo.

usa. values para cada botón y así sabrás en la ejecución del script cual botón se toco.

Algo como por ejemplo:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="guardar_btn" value="saldos" class="btn btn-danger">
    Actualizar Saldos
  </button>
  <!-- Todos los campos del formulario para actualizar saldos-->
  <?php
     if($_POST['guardar_btn'] === 'saldos'){
         $ActualizarSaldos = new ControladorSaldos();
         $ActualizarSaldos -> ctrActualizarSaldos();
     }
  ?>
</form>

<!-- Modal Registrar Compras -->
<div id="modalRegistrarCompras" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <form role="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <!-- Todos los campos del formulario para registrar compras-->
    <button type="submit" name="guardar_btn" value="compras" class="btn btn-primary">
      Registrar Compras
    </button>
    <?php
      if($_POST['guardar_btn'] === 'compras'){
          registrarCompra = new ControladorCompras();
          $registrarCompra -> ctrRegistrarCompras();
      }
    ?>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Intenté con tu sugerencia pero sigue enviado los dos formularios. Lo peor de todo es que el de saldos lo envía vacío y como es un `update`, borra los datos que tengo en la `BD`.  _Aclaro que no es por tu sugerencia sino que es el comportamiento que tengo desde el principio_

Comment: entonces tu problema esta en otra porción de código que no es la que compartiste. Es imposible ejecutar el código dentro del if si no se cumple la condición. y como son condiciones contradictorias no pueden ejecutarse al mismo tiempo. Si quieres estar seguro. dentro de cada if escribe un echo o un var?dump. y veras que no se ejecutan las 2 al mismo tiempo.